# using pikaday datepicker when using apostrophe-schemas to create contact form

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a contact form which is working as expected though apostrophe-schemas, here the view:

```
{% import "apostrophe-schemas:macros.html" as schemas %}
<form class="contact-form-tandt" data-contact-form-tandt>
  {{ schemas.fields(data.schema, { tabs: false, placeholder: true }) }}
</form>
```

However when I have a date field in the piece such as:

```
 {
   name: 'dob',
   type: 'date',
   label: 'Date of Birth',
   placeholder: 'Date of Birth:',
   pikadayOptions: {
     format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
     firstDay: 1
    }
  }
```

The pikaday code is included on the page but doesn't appear to be bound to the actual date field. Do I need to trigger this through the configured always.js, if so how should this be done, because this feels really hacky?

```
var picker = new Pikaday({ field:  $('[name="dob"]')[0] });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best guide for this is [apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets). If you aren't already using it, or [Apostrophe Forms](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-forms) I suggest using one or the other for this.

A couple of key steps that it does is [run `apos.schemas.populate`](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets/blob/c1c2403d0f6cdb9da2bc2845bcc860be14626afb/public/js/user.js#L11-L19), which for the date field includes using the `apos.ui.enhanceDate` method to [pass the Pikaday options in and connect that to the field](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/main/lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/public/js/user.js#L1541-L1554). That's probably the piece you're missing.

You could certainly replicate what apos-pieces-submit-widgets is doing, but I would recommend using that module and following its documentation instead if you want to "roll your own" at all. Otherwise Apostrophe Forms is pretty nice. More forms documentation: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/forms.html#building-forms-with-apostrophe